Cancellation of asynchronous tasks in C#
Problem statement
I develop a Multi-platform App UI (MAUI). I use the community toolkit to bind a command to the TextChanged event of a searchbar. In a nutshell, this command searches elements in a List<string> that begins with the searchbar.Text property. The related code below:
// Occurring methods and variables
[ObservableProperty]
List<string> selectedTopicNames;

CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

List<string> GetNames() => topics.TopicsData.Select(element => element.Name).ToList();

// The actual method
[RelayCommand]
async Task PerformSearchAsync(string keyWord)
{
    await cts.CancelAsync();
    cts = new();
    // Fire and forget a task to search for the keyword
    _ = Task.Run(() => 
    {
        try 
        {
            // Get all names
            List<string> names = GetNames();

            // Perform case-insensitive search
            List<string> result = names.Where(name => 
            {
                cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                return name.StartsWith(keyWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }).ToList();

            if (!result.SequenceEqual(SelectedTopicNames))
            {
                SelectedTopicNames = result;
            }
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException) { }
    });
}

The main idea is to fire and forget a task that performs the search operation and rewrites the property SelectedTopicNames that is binded to a CollectionView. I found it to be a good solution because when you reassign the SelectedTopicNames it will fire the OnPropertyChanged event which will notify the UI it's time to refresh the displayed data. This can take a while due to it has to add 90 button to the UI in worst case scenario.
Since the task has to write SelectedTopicNames, I thought it would be nice to cancel the ongoing task in order to avoid possible concurrent writing and firing unnecessarily the OnPropertyChanged event.
My concern is that, according to the documentation of CancelAsync(), it will only await the process of signalling aka. the completion of the registered callbacks therefore it won't await the actual cancellation of the task. In this case, if the ongoing task can't hit the line ThrowIfCancellationRequested between the signalling and the reinitialization of the cancellation token source then it won't be cancelled and a concurrent task will be started.
Failed solutions

Currently, as you can see I palced the ThrowIfCancellationRequested inside the LINQ query because that's the only place where I can use it effectively. Because GetNames() is also a LINQ and there's no purpose to make it async to be cancelable and SequenceEqual also doesn't support cancellation. This approach doesn't quarantee the task will be canceled.
I feel that the usage of callbacks are also a dead end because based on the documentations you can't cancel on-going tasks in it rather it's used to clean up unsupervised resources.

Desired behaviour
I want to achieve such a behaviour if the command is invoked before an ongoing task could finish then the ongoing task is immediatly cancelled or at least it won't execute the assigment of SelectedTopicNames = result;. (Main purpose is to not throw OnPropertyChanged event because that implies the UI update.)

Your code should most probably look like
await cts.CancelAsync();
cts = new();
var token = cts.Token;
try{
    var selectedTopicNames = await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        
            // Get all names
            List<string> names = GetNames();

            // Perform case-insensitive search
            List<string> result = names.Where(name => 
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                return name.StartsWith(keyWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }).ToList();

            if (!result.SequenceEqual(SelectedTopicNames))
            {
                return result;
            }
            return null;        
    });
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    if(selectedTopicNames != null){
        SelectedTopicNames = selectedTopicNames;
    }
}
catch(OperationCanceledException) { }

This fixes a few issues. First of all the property is correctly updated on the UI thread. And since the cancellation token is checked on the UI thread the setting of the property and the cancellation will be correctly ordered.

Because GetNames() is also a LINQ

GetNames() returns a List<string>, so there is nothing lazy or LINQy about that, it is just a plain list in memory.
Note that I would recommend doing some performance measurement. A rule of thumb is to not block the UI thread more than 50ms, and a quick test suggests that this should equal roughly 200k strings. So how many strings do you have, and how long do your operation take? Is cancellation and threading really needed?

In this case, can the token throw OperationalException even if the task (that provides the selectedTopicNames result) hasn't finished yet? I'm not sure threading is needed. Previously when I didn't use threading, adding the buttons to the UI was very slow and blocked the UI. But in this case, the UI structure was different than now, for example, the collection view was part of a scroll view and vertical stack layout combo and I read bad things about it because it can mess up the virtualization support.

@supersonic-developer Nothing after await Task.Run will run until the awaited task has finished, and if the task finishes with an exception, that will be re-thrown by the await. My recommendation is to measure/benchmark/profile the code before any optimization, and try to find algorithmic improvements, or avoid doing unnecessary work, before throwing threads at the problem.
